# Algebraic geometry over groups: zero-divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

In *Algebraic Geometry over Groups*, Baumslag, Myasnikov, and Remeslennikov define a $G$-group to be a group $H$ together with a group homomorphism $G \hookrightarrow H$.  Then they define a *zero-divisor* in $H$ to be an element $x \in H$ for which there is some $y$ satisfying
$$[x, y^g] = 1 \qquad \text{ for all } g \in G$$

See for instance the beginning of Section 1.3 on page 4 [here](https://web.stevens.edu/algebraic/alexeim/Publications/All_files_new/FINAL_AL_51_38.pdf).

Can someone say something about the motivation for this definition, and how the analogy to the ring-theoretic case works?  Previously they've defined an $H$-module as a homomorphism of $G$-groups $H \to {\rm Aut}(A)$, so at first it appeared that the analogy here might be that we're taking only the multiplicative structure of a commutative ring.  But that doesn't seem to carry across here.

(My tags here are sort of a random guess.  Feel free to improve.)

Comment: Can you add a link of this text, and where this is written?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Done.

Comment: Great! Section $2.1$ has many results about $G$-domains; this explains the motivation about having no "zero-divisors".

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I saw that, but I don't understand the analogy between products in a ring and commutators in a group.

Comment: The analogy, namely zero-divisors in rings and $G$-zero divisors for groups becomes only clear by the analogous results, not directly with commutators.

Comment: I believe your question would better fit on mathoverflow (then add the generic tag gr.group-theory)

Comment: @YCor: My understanding was that MO was only for research-level questions, not basic questions about papers you're reading.

Comment: But this is definitely a research-level paper, not a topic that is covered in standard textbooks or standard undergraduate courses.